# emacs change indentation style specifically for c++

Tags: emacs, indentation

I would like to change the indentation style when I edit C++ files in my `.emacs` to 4-spaces instead of what seems to be the default current 2-spaces. I don't want the style to change for other languages, only for C++. How can I define this in my `.emacs` configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq c-basic-offset 4)))
```